# I turned off hardware's acceleration in Chrome and Chrome stopped working couldn't get it to start again. Already uninstalled it and reinstalled it

Tags: acceleration

I turned off hardware's acceleration in Chrome and Chrome stopped working couldn't get it to start again. I uninstalled it and reinstalled it still can't get it to start again.

Comment: See if Chrome opens in a new operating system User Profile. Disabling hardware acceleration should not break Chrome.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Try to uninstall Chrome using [Revo Uninstaller Free](https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-uninstaller-free/), verify that all Chrome folders have been deleted, then reinstall again.